# Comment in fixed line in Excel gets truncated when I scroll down

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel sheet with a fixed header (first row is fixed) and some of the cells in this header contain comments. When I don't scroll down and hover over the cell, the comment is fully visible, but when I scroll down, only the first line of the comment is visible (everything which fits into the first row). Is there a way to always show the full comment?

I'm using Excel 2010 but a possible solution should preferably also work in Excel 2013.

I think it's clearer with these two screenshots:
[image: not scrolled, comment visible]
[image: scrolled, comment truncated]

P.S.: I don't know if this is the right place to ask this. I searched around but I think there's no clear decision: [Meta 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions)/[Meta 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solution:

1. Use a macro to re-position the comment so its top-left corner is on a cell in the first visible row **below** the header row.
2. Expand the height of the header row to fully include the comment.

I use the second option:

[image: scrolled]

**EDIT#1**

There is a **third** option:

Use a *Data validation* message rather than a *Comment.*  The DV message will be visible regardless of scrolling up or down.

Comment: The first option is beyond my skills and the second doesn't work as the text is quite long sometimes. But the third one looks definitely promising, thanks!

Comment: Most people use **DV** to check data inputs, but they can also serve as a substitute for a **Comment!**

Comment: A fourth option would be for all Excel users to request Microsoft to "fix bugs before adding new features" (here for example: https://excel.uservoice.com/ or probably more here: https://answers.microsoft.com/). The number of Microsoft products' workaround shared on internet is amazing. Even Microsoft is working with workarounds through their technical support.

Comment: @VincentAgami ........................ ** I Agree ** ....................